# Verify the limit using the formal definition

Tags: limits

Verify

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(5+x)}{x^2}=0$

using the formal definition of a limit. I haven't had much trouble with other formal limit questions, but in this case, I can't figure out how to write $x$ in terms of $\epsilon$. How do you approach this question?

Comment: Would it help to separate it into $\frac{5}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: Note that limits to infinity are defined a tad bit differently than most other limits are. Basically, let $0<\frac{5+x}{x^2}<\epsilon$, and after solving, you'd find that $$\epsilon x^2-x-5>0$$Which happens when $x>\frac{1+\sqrt{1+20\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}$. Does this give you a sufficient hint?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because you are afraid to simplify. Use intermediate inequalities first to reduce the complexity, then bound the result.

$x\to\infty$ so we can assume $x>5$ and then $(x+5)<2x$

So we get $0<\dfrac{5+x}{x^2}<\dfrac 2x<\varepsilon\quad$ for $x>\delta$ where $\delta=\max(5,\frac 2\varepsilon)$

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler by observing that for large $x$, we get that $\frac{5+x}{x^2} < \frac{6x}{x^2} = \frac{6}{x}$. Now let $\varepsilon>0$. We must show that for $x>N$ we have $\vert \frac{5 + x}{x^2} - 0 \vert < \varepsilon$. Let $N= \frac{6}{\varepsilon}$. We then get $\vert \frac{5 + x}{x^2} - 0 \vert < \frac{6}{x} \leq \frac{6}{\frac{6}{\varepsilon}} = \varepsilon$.